# Matching characters in text string in a column then invoke function

Tags: google-apps-script

I am formatting race age categories. I need to search a column for M, W or F within a string, e.g. W40, U20M, Senior F, and run a function if any of the character exists in the column or run another function if the characters are not present.

I currently have the code below but I can't get it to do what I need. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
function master() {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sh.getRange("Imported!E2:E50").getValue();
  if (/[MWF][\d-]+/.test(cell)) {
    import3();
  } else {
    import2();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Range.getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) will only return the value of the cell E2.

Use `Range.getValues()` instead to get the whole column.

If you just need to see if the value appears at all in the whole column, then you can use the array built-in methods `reduce` and `some` to test the column.

```js
function master() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var column = sh.getRange("Imported!E2:E50").getValues();
  var values = column.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
      return accumulator.concat(currentValue);
    },
    []
  );
  var containsKey = values.some(function (value) { return /[MWF][\d-]+/.test(value); });
  if (containsKey) {
    import3();
  } else {
    import2();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @dwmorrin It doesn't seem to work in my sheet. Is my regex ok? I am looking for any instance of either M, W or F in any cell in the column within any text string. If it finds an instance it should execute the import3() function. Otherwise run the import2() function. Hope I'm explaining myself adequately. Thank you.

Comment: I have sorted it thank you. I deleted [\d-]+/  to just leave a check for [MWF] down the column and this seems to be producing the result I need. Thanks again.